# Python Errno2 keeps occuring

Tags: python, python-2.7, powershell, cmd

So I've recently started going through Zed Shaw's LPTHW and on exercise 1 where it asks to run the ex1.py in CMD, I keep getting the following error message:

python: can't open file 'ex1.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

I've read through the other answers and followed the instructions therein, and have added the following Paths to the System Variables:

- Path
- %PY_HOME%;%PY_HOME%\Lib;%PY_HOME%\DLLs;%PY_HOME%\Lib\lib-tk;
- PY_HOME
- C:\Python27
- PYTHONPATH
- %PY_HOME%\Lib;%PY_HOME%\DLLs;%PY_HOME%\Lib\lib-tk;C:\another-library

Also, when I type Python into either CMD or PowerShell it returns the three >>> prompts that I believe are supposed to appear.

I'm not sure what else there is to add or edit anywhere to allow me to run Python scripts in either CMD or terminal. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: At exercise 1 he warns not to use an IDE or IDLE. So I guess you used Notepad and didn't change the filetype when saving, and the file is actually saved as `ex1.py.txt` but you have "hide file extensions for known types" on in Explorer so it looks like it's called `ex1.py` ? Otherwise, provide the full path to it, e.g. `c:\> python c:\users\username\documents\python\ex1.py` or wherever, and see if that runs?

Answer (score 0):

When you open a shell (cmd.exe or powershell.exe), if you can type python and you get the ">>>" prompt, then your path is OK.  From the shell, use the dir command to see if your file is there:

```
C:\users\jsmith> dir

Directory: C:\users\jsmith

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a----         8/5/2016  11:33 PM       3331 script5.py
```

If you don't see the file (ex1.py), you need to figure out where you saved it.  Or it could be what @TessellatingHeckler said.  Can you open ex1.py using Recent Items from the Start Menu by right clicking on the file and selecting edit?  If so, you can select file and save as from the menu to find the directory where the file is saved.  Then use that path from the shell to load it in python:

```
python "C:\Users\jsmith\My Documents\ex1.py"
```

---

Troubleshooting steps:

- Are you using cmd.exe or powershell.exe for your shell?
- After opening your shell, run the command:  pwd
- Run the command:  dir
- Execute your Python script with the full path:  python "C:\Users\jsmith\My Documents\ex1.py"
- Now change to the directory where your script is:  cd "C:\Users\jsmith\My Documents\"
- Execute:  pwd
- Execute:  dir
- Execute:  python ex1.py
- Paste all the output verbatim.  You need to paste it in as a code block (each line must be preceded by four spaces).

Example output:

- Running powershell.exe

> C:\users\jsmith> pwd
>
> Path:
>
> C:\users\jsmith

```
C:\users\jsmith> dir                                

Directory: C:\users\jsmith                      

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                  
----                -------------     ------ ----                  
d-----        2/15/2017   3:54 PM            Desktop
(...) 

C:\users\jsmith> python "C:\apps\working\python\general\input-intro1.py"

Enter your name:  George

Hello George

cd \apps\working\python\general

C:\apps\working\python\general> pwd

Path:

C:\apps\working\python\general

C:\apps\working\python\general> dir                                

Directory: C:\apps\working\python\general                      

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                  
----                -------------     ------ ----                  
d-----        2/15/2017   3:54 PM            sprintintro           
-a----        10/6/2015   9:18 PM        222 input-intro1.py    

C:\users\jsmith> python input-intro1.py\
(show error message...)
```

Please let me know if any questions on this--Jim

Comment: Using the full document location in CMD and using the Python command with it runs the document in CMD, thanks for that. Is there a way to run it through the dir and cd commands though? I can navigate to the folder using those commands but the moment I run python ex1.py it returns the Errno 2 message again. Do you know what the problem there is?

Comment: @YusufBismillah - please see my revised answer above and provide the requested output.

Comment: @YusufBismillah - when you execute any program (such as Python), and tell it to load a file (for example, your script "ex1.py"), it looks in the current working directory.  That's typically the directory you launched the program from.  If the file/script you're trying to load isn't in the current working directory, you need to provide either a relative or absolute path to reach it.  For example, python directory1\ex1.py or python "C:\Users\jsmith\My Documents\Directory1\ex1.py".